# Meaning of a poetic phrase (in Melville's "Misgivings")

Tags: poetry, poetic

Herman Melville wrote the poem "Misgivings," which is impressive and, seemingly at least, about the American Civil War.

Its last line is, "*The hemlock shakes in the rafter, the oak in the driving keel.*"

What does that mean?

Comment: Strictly speaking, unless you have questions about specific words or phrases, literary analysis is off-topic here. However, you may get some takers. You may be interested in committing to support the [Literature.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature) site.

Answer (score 3):

It may help to understand the timeline of US elections and the timeline of Melville's life. Melville returned from a ship's voyage a week after the election of 1860. The US holds a popular vote for Presidential electors in November of years evenly divisible by four. The electors meet to certify their votes in December. Congress counts the votes (for the election of 1860, this happened in February of 1861), and the winner is inaugurated after that. For the election of 1860, the winner was Abraham Lincoln, and he took office in March 1861.

By the time Melville returned home, South Carolina had already declared its intention to secede, which it did about two weeks after the electoral college met. So Americans watched a slow-motion, five-month slide to the breakup of the union and the inevitable start of war (which began about a month after Lincoln took office).

Melville wrote "Misgivings" during the fear and apprehension of the lull between the 1860 election and the shots fired at Fort Sumter in 1861. When he writes

> The hemlock shakes in the **rafter**, the oak in the driving **keel**

he's literally talking about (respectively) the main supporting beams of a house and a ship, two structures that are no-longer solid and safe because their main supports are no longer solid and safe. Figuratively, he's talking about the underpinnings of his country.

Comment: So...you think the reference to domestic ("rafter") and foreign ("keel") policy was unintentional?

Comment: I think the contrast is between landlubber and sailor rather than between domestic and foreign.

Comment: Great answer! But what about the second part? Is what is meant by the "driving keel" the steering of a boat? Is the keel made of oak? Is the oak shaking, as the deadly hemlock in the rafters?

Comment: Rafters are ship's timbers too. The contrast is between above and below. This is just another take on the versatile  "shiver me timbers" idiom that was very widespread at the time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiver_my_timbers